# C# compiler/IDE for Redhat Enterprise Linux 7?

Tags: rhel, compiler, c#

Can someone point me to C# compiler/IDE  for Redhat Enterprise Linux 7 ?

Comment: There's [a mono version of Eclipse](http://www.mono-project.com/archived/mono_for_linux_developers/) fwiw.

Answer (score 0):

- [MonoDevelop](http://www.monodevelop.com/)
- [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) – primarily meant for .Net Core